# What does ~=. mean in Stata?

Tags: stata

What does the `~=.` operator mean in Stata?

Comment: Stata has an encyclopedia-sized set of searchable [pdf documentation](http://www.stata.com/features/documentation/). You may find sections 12.2.1 and 13.2.4 useful.

Answer (score 4):

From [this page](http://dss.princeton.edu/online_help/stats_packages/stata/stata_gen.htm) it appears that `~=.` means `Not Equal to a Missing Number`.

Comment: Correct in so far as period is system missing. But the condition could be true because the implicit operand is an extended missing value from `.a` to `.z'.